# Merge an object with an Activerecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my current project, I need to add a record to an ActiveRecord::Relation. I can't use it as an array, because I need to apply an ordering scope after the "merge" (and then, also pagination). The problem is that I can't find the way to do it in a "nice" way.

The relation that I need to merge is very simple: a typical friendship association. Essentially, I need a relation with all the friends of a user AND the user. If I could use Arrays, it would be something as simple as:

```
user.friends + [user]
```

But I need a Relation. Now I'm using this scope:

```
scope :user_and_friends, lambda { |user| includes(:friendships).where(Friendship.arel_table["friend_id"].eq(user.id).or(arel_table["id"].eq(user.id))) }
```

But it's terribly slow. Can you help me?

Comment: Your relation seems fine, maybe need an index somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found the solution by myself. The new scope is like this:

```
scope :user_and_friends, lambda { |user| joins(:friendships).where(Friendship.arel_table["friend_id"].eq(user.id).or(User.arel_table["id"].eq(user.id))).group("user_id") }
```

`joins`is much faster than `includes`, specially when you have lots of records. The only problem for this scope is the duplicated records that `joins`generates, but that is solved thanks to `group`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
scope :user_and_friends, lambda { |user| user.friends.merge(user) }
```

A little about [merge method](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3) (Associations section).

At least you can do this:

```
user.friends.merge(user)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. `NoMethodError: undefined method `default_scoped?'`

Comment: Does the User table have a friends association?

Comment: Yes. The problem with this scope if that "user" is an object, and not a Relation. It's possible to replace it with `User.where("id = ?", user.id)`.

But anyway, a merge works like an AND. I need an OR.

Comment: This merge is certainly is Relation method, check the link.

Comment: Yeah, but merge needs another Relation as a parameter. And user is not a Relation.

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you, so try the merge method with last update.